# Is there a way to detect if iAd is showing "Test Advertisement"?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, iad, ads

I have an app in the appstore and I seem to getting a lot of users who seem to only see "Test Advertisement" with iAds (usually because they have appsync running or their device is jailbroken). So I would know if there is way to detect if the iad showing to the user is a "Test Advertisement". This way, we can notify the user. Or even better, is there a way to detect what ad is being displayed to the user?

Thanks,

Great job guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find out if the user is seeing a test advertisement banner. The only way I have found is if the request and impressions are high but you are making no money out of the ads. But as of now, I don't know any way to see what ad is being displayed to the user. You may want to try to download your app straight from the app store and see if you are also getting a test advertisement banner. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I would think if the adview is basically javascript, it would be possible to get it's content. I thought about programmatically taking a screenshot of the ad area and determining if it is black. I am sure I can take the screenshot but I don't know how to determine the average color of say a 2px by 2px crop from the ad area. Do you know how? Do you think this would work?

Comment: Try reading this, it's a post about checking how similar a image is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488732/how-does-one-compare-one-image-to-another-to-see-if-they-are-similar-by-a-certain Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I was also thinking of OCRing the image to check if the words "test advertisement" is in it. Do you have/know any OCR classes I can use?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5359-ocr.html BTW if I helped you out, could you please mark my answer as correct? Thanks, sorry if i sound a little rude but i'm new to stack overflow and i'm trying to raise my rating. Hope that article helps!

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Did you find any solutions ?