#  Uitouch moved animation 

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

in my app i draw a line in touch moved action..and if i will stop at the a point..so i want a animation from beginning to end....how can i do that.....

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to sample the image on the screen to see if it is the same as the fully painted image.  [stackoverflow.com/questions/6488732/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488732/) Hope this helps.

Comment: this is good..but how i know that the image is fully painted or not.

Comment: If the picture you have that should be painted is the same as the picture that is getting painted

Comment: my question is i have a picture in UIImage view..the picture is empty..and i am drawing the image...after that how can i know the picture is fully painted and not...i hope u understand my problem.........            .................//empty color image url http://my.imageshack.us/edit.php?url[]=16/4444/721702228/letteram.gif/y                              
//fully painted url 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/letteraq.png

Comment: I don't know, you will have to set a boundary and make sure everything inside the boundary is coded.

Comment: yes i want to paint inside the boundary...and after that give a action...