# iOS how to find duplicate images from photo library fast?

Tags: ios, objective-c, duplicates, compare, photos

I want to find duplicate photos from photo library fast I'm using following code for retrieving duplicate image but its time taking :

```
UIImage *img1 = [imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
UIImage *img2 = [imgArray objectAtIndex:j];

NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img1, 1.0);
NSLog(@"%@",data1);
NSData *data2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img2, 1.0);
NSLog(@"%@",data2);


            if ([data1 isEqualToData:data2])
            {
                    [duparray addObject:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                    [duparray addObject:[imageArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"no");
            }
```

getting the data and comparing 1000 photos waste of time 
can anyone help me for this, help will be appreciated.. thank you

Comment: Set same code in background queue or you need to find duplicate using image Name

Comment: but if i click 2 image with similar pose the the name will be different the image will be the same ....then ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to compare two images will be comparing both images **bit by bit** for equality. If you shoot similar pics, the comparison will lead to **inequality**. If you want duplicate pics removed that have same data composition, the current code will be working fine. If you want to include similar pics to pass equality test, you need to use different logic to compare. And btw, do not run this code in main thread. Run it **asynchronously** if it's a long-running task.

When using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, try to compress (`0.5 or lower`) the images instead of setting the quality to `1.0`, which might lead to some improvement.

To compare images, and check if they're similar to a certain percentage, you can check out this answer from SO:

[Compare one image to another to see if they are similar by a certain percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488838/5912335)

Comment: can you suggest me some logic for that? I'm searching for that logic only...@Badhan Ganesh

Comment: what about width, height and the getRGBForX ?
thats not mention in that answer brother....

Comment: can you suggest another way of comparing image which just slightly different from each other?

Comment: You can check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19668235/5912335) from the same post I shared. I haven't tried it, but you'll get full implementation and usage of the image comparison. Hope that helps solve your problem.

Comment: i tried this its not working for me because if the image is little bit different then it will not return true for duplicate image suppose i take two images i 1st image I'm standing in the middle of the image and in another i standing little bit away from the centre with the same pose then this will not work of me and one image is blur and another is clear then also it will not return true its becoming headache now please help me to get  out of this

Comment: Yeah! Because pixels from two images differ more than we see directly with our eyes .. It's tricky to get this working. This is what google announced in Google IO 2017. They use machine learning to identify similarities in images and they seem to use Complex algorithms to process the images to know whether they are really similar as wee see it with out eyes.

Comment: yap!! and i searched on app store there are only 2 apps for removing duplicate images don't know what logic they have applied behind it check out if you get some logic form that photo cleaner is the name this is link https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/cleaner-delete-duplicate-photos-clean-storage/id1185450847?mt=8

Comment: have you got any logic related what he must have done ......?@Badhan Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

A similar topic is discussed and there are good suggestions. Reading can be beneficial.

[Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)

Comment: its discussion i need some logical and coding help for iOS (objective c)